# absolute paths of lines in a file matching a pattern

Tags: bash

I have a c program and I want the absolute paths of the headers in that c program in to a separate file.I have used the following command

```
find  "${pwd)" -name "#include" > file.txt.
```

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please show us an example of your input C files. Do we need to expand the `include` to find the full path? What is your `find` command supposed to do? There is a syntax error and you seem to be searching for files named `#include`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @NGRhodes this is 100% on topic here and actually _not_ on topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for header files that are contained, directly or indirectly, in the current directory--and assuming they all have `.h` suffixes an no *other* files are named that way--you can just search for files whose names end in `.h`:

```bash
find "$PWD" -name '*.h' >file.txt
```

You can write `"$(pwd)"` in place of `"$PWD"` if you like. If you had literally used `"${pwd)"`, as shown in your question, then that won't work, because you cannot close an opening `{` with a `)`. But you were on the right track, because using `.` would just give you relative paths instead of absolute ones.

The reason `name "#include"` doesn't work is that `-name` specifies a name or pattern to be matched by *filenames*. When you include a header file in C, you do use the `#include` directive, but this is not part of the name.

---

On the other hand, if you only want to find header files that are used in your program, or you want to find header files that are contained outside the program's directory tree (which I presume to be the current directory), then you may need to examine the contents of files.

You might be able to obtain the information from a file like `Makefile` or `CMakeLists.txt`, if you're using such a system. Otherwise, or if that turns out not to give you what you need, then you'll want to look into what features your compiler provides to do this. If you're using `gcc` or `clang`, that's the `-M` and `-MM` options. The difference is that `-MM` doesn't list system headers. The format this shows is, for each `filename.c` file passed to the compiler:

```
filename.o: filename.c headers...
```

where **`headers...`** is a list of paths to header files, separated either by spaces or by a space followed by a backslash followed by a newline, depending on how long the paths are.

The output is shown this way because its main purpose it to specify dependencies for building each translation unit of a program or library. The syntax emitted can be used in a makefile. Based on your description, it sounds like this isn't the syntax you want. You can likely process the output into the format you need. (For example, if none of the headers have whitespace characters in them and you're okay with duplicates, you could [pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) the output to a command like `grep -oP '\S+\.h(?:\s|$)'`.)

---

Because I don't know quite what header files you actually need to list--and that you may have to experiment to find that out for yourself--I've refrained from covering that aspect of the matter in detail. Once you figure out exactly what headers you need and how they should be figured out, whatever text processing remains will likely be the simpler part.

`gcc` and `clang` also support an `-H` option, which you might try, but I am guessing it will tend to give much more output than you want. See [How to tell where a header file is included from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834778/how-to-tell-where-a-header-file-is-included-from); [`man gcc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gcc.1.html); and the [GCC reference manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/), especially [section 3.12](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options), for more information.